# Angular two way databinding

Tags: angularjs, data-binding

I am here asking this question because I seem to be missing something. I can databind 2 items just fine. I can even run a calculation on the result, like number / 2, for example.

The issue i am having is the result changing in real time. Some code:

```
   var app = angular.module('base_app', []);

   app.controller('testCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){

   $scope.percentage = 50;

   $scope.total = $scope.percentage / 2;
   }]);
```

And the html content:

```
   <div class="col-sm-12" ng-controller="testCtrl">
      <input type="text"  ng-model="percentage" />
      <p>{{percentage}}</p>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-12" ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <p>{{total}}</p>
  </div>
```

So what i am looking to do, is when $scope.percentage is updated via the 2 way data bind, I want $scope.total to update as well.

if percentage was 50, then total would be 25. If i changed the input to 20, then total should update to 10, but it is not, and this where i am stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do that with ng-change

```
<div class="col-sm-12" ng-controller="testCtrl">
      <input type="text" ng-change="Update()"  ng-model="percentage" />
      <p>{{percentage}}</p>
  </div>
```

In controller,

```
$scope.Update = function (){
  $scope.total = $scope.percentage / 2;
}
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/EPuPwyxPijLVuwjetcYO?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to put parent div tag and intialize controller to that div.

For Ex.

```
<div ng-controller="testCtrl">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
      <input type="text" ng-model="percentage" ng-change="updateTotal()"/>
      <p>{{percentage}}</p>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <p>{{total}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

and add updateTotal() function in controller

```
$scope.updateTotal = function (){
  $scope.total = $scope.percentage / 2;
}
```